# How do I get the middle value of a string using Regexp in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, regex-negation

I need to get everything but the first 6 digits and last 4 of a card number without special chars, which is a string that can be as follow:

4500 1234 5678 7654
Or
4500-1234-5678-7654

So I would need to get: 345678

So far I was able to get the inverse values out using this:

```
^(\d[\- ]?){6}|[\- ]|(\d[\- ]?){4}$
```

Note: I'm using match() instead of replace() due to the business-specific use case in Nodejs.

UPDATE:
Thanks, everyone for your help so far! It actually needs to be in one function if possible. Also, credit cards' length variate from 13 to 18 digits, which makes problematic to rely on its length or position to get mid value.

Comment: Use a regexp to remove everything except digits, then use `substr()`

Comment: You can't do this with a single regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it in two steps. First, remove all the non-digits with a regexp replacement. Then use `substring()` to get the desired substring.

```js
function middle_digits(cardnum) {
  let nondigits = cardnum.replace(/\D/g, '');
  return nondigits.substring(6, nondigits.length-4);
}
console.log(middle_digits('4500 1234 5678 7654'));
console.log(middle_digits('4500-1234-5678-7654'))
```

Comment: With [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), you can pass a negative `endIndex`, and the function becomes: `return cardnum.replace(/\D/g, '').slice(6, -4);`

Comment: That's still two steps, thought it's a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second group of `(\d{4}[ -]+\d{2})(\d{2}[ -]*\d{4})`

See https://regex101.com/r/CFoh7m/1

Comment: This will include the punctuation in the result.

Comment: Thanks, that was close! But the thing is the card's length could be of 13 to 18 digits and this would only capture a part of it. Also as @Barmar indicated, it would be including punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the requirement to match numbers excluding fillers (spaces and dashes) as stated is not possible with a single regex. You can match multiple groups, then combine them. Or, you can match the required range, and then filter out the fillers. here is the latter approach:

```js
const input = [
  '4500 1234 5678 7654',
  '4500-1234-5678-9012',
  '1234-5678-9012-3',
  '1234-5678-9012-3456-78'
];
const regex = /(?<=^(\d(?:[^\d]?)){6})((?:\d[^\d]?){3,})(?=(?:\d[^\d]?){4}$)/;
input.forEach(str => {
  let matched = str.match(regex);
  let cleaned = matched[0].replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
  console.log(str);
  console.log('=> matched: ' +matched);
  console.log('=> cleaned: ' +cleaned);
});
```

Output:

```
4500 1234 5678 7654
=> matched: 34 5678 ,4,34 5678 
=> cleaned: 345678
4500-1234-5678-9012
=> matched: 34-5678-,4,34-5678-
=> cleaned: 345678
1234-5678-9012-3
=> matched: 78-9,1,78-9
=> cleaned: 789
1234-5678-9012-3456-78
=> matched: 78-9012-34,1,78-9012-34
=> cleaned: 78901234
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=^(\d(?:[^\d]?)){6})` - positive lookbehind scanning from start over 6 numbers, each followed by optional filler
- `((?:\d[^\d]?){3,})` - capture group, expect 3+ numbers, each followed by optional filler
- `(?=(?:\d[^\d]?){4}$)` - positive lookahead scanning over 4 numbers, each followed by optional filler, up to end of string